# How to wrap a value between boundaries?

Tags: glsl, shader

How can I wrap a value around arbitrary boundaries? I want to avoid if checks, so I have come up with this that works for a low boundary using step:

```
float check = step(-1, val)*2.0-1.0;
val *= check;
```

This will output whatever value the vector `val` has when it is greater than -1, and wrap around, and jump to 1 when it exceeds it.

My goal is that when a value exceeds a certain threshold, it "wraps" up and starts back from the opposite side of the screen. So, if a moving dot for example exceeds 1, then it will re-appear in the screen in the -1 position, and keep on moving from there on.

On the other hand if is below -1, it will appear in position 1 and keep moving from there.

Comment: My apologies! I gave the first two lines just as an example of separate if statements (and they had a typo!) I edited my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> float check = step(-1, val)*2.0-1.0;
> ```

> This will effectively output whatever value the vector val has in its components whenever that value is greater than -1, and wrap around and jump to 1 when it exceeds it.

No. The result of the function [`step()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) is eiterh 0.0 or 1.0, in any case. So the result of `step(-1, val)*2.0-1.0` is either -1.0 or 1.0.

---

> My goal is that when a value exceeds a certain threshold, it "wraps" up and starts back from the opposite side of the screen. So, if a moving dot for example exceeds 1, then it will re-appear in the screen in the -1 position,

What you want to do can be achieved by the function `mod(x, y)`https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mod.xhtml, which returns the rest of the division of x by y:

```c
y = mod(x - min, max - min) + min
```

For an ascent from -1 to +1 this results in

```c
y = mod(x + 1.0, 2.0) - 1.0
```

Independent on the value of `x` has, the result of the function is always in the range [-1, 1]. If the upper limit 1 is reached the immediately following result is -1:

[image]

Note, the function uses `mod()`https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mod.xhtml support `genType`. This means `x` and `y` can even be of type `vec2`, `vec3` or `vec4`. Of course `x` and `y` have to be of the same type.